# Load Web Content From Different APK

Tags: android, resources, webview, assets

I have an Android app that reads content from a different APK. Videos, and pictures can be loaded from the other APK and displayed just fine. I also want to be able to load a web site from the other APK as well. I can currently load a single page by extracting the text from the resource and putting it into a WebView. This is great, but I need it to load an entire site (multiple web pages, pictures, etc.). Can anyone tell me how I can do this? Can I get a URL to a different APK's res or asset directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest route to go is probably to send the web site as a zip archive. You would then simply send it as a single file as you do with your videos and picture.

When your APK receives the zip file it is fairly easy to decompress the archive and browse the website.